# auto-py-to-exe cannot get rid of torch and torchvision errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller, torch, torchvision, auto-py-to-exe

I've been reading every single post I found here and online with similar problems but none solved my problem.

I am trying to convert my python app to a exe file using auto-py-to-exe.
I got rid of most of the errors exept one. The application starts, but does not work as torch isnt loaded properly. the errors I get at startup are:

```
C:\yolov5\VisionExe\main\torch\_jit_internal.py:750: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x000001F88C9C6EE8>.
  warnings.warn(f"Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: {func}.")
C:\yolov5\VisionExe\main\torch\_jit_internal.py:750: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x000001F88C9CD048>.
  warnings.warn(f"Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: {func}.")
C:\yolov5\VisionExe\main\torchvision\io\image.py:11: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension:
```

The command I run to compile is this:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/cratedb.db3;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/database.db3;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.onnx;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.yaml;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/MainWindow.ui;." --hidden-import "pytorch"  "C:/yolov5/Vision/main.py"
```

the compiling log is this:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.18.1
Building directory: C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/cratedb.db3;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/database.db3;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.onnx;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.yaml;." --add-data "C:/yolov5/Vision/MainWindow.ui;." --hidden-import "pytorch"  "C:/yolov5/Vision/main.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --add-data C:/yolov5/Vision/cratedb.db3;. --add-data C:/yolov5/Vision/database.db3;. --add-data C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.onnx;. --add-data C:/yolov5/Vision/EPS_GB.yaml;. --add-data C:/yolov5/Vision/MainWindow.ui;. --hidden-import pytorch C:/yolov5/Vision/main.py --distpath C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\application --workpath C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build --specpath C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s

3645500 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.10
3645502 INFO: Python: 3.7.8
3645504 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
3645506 INFO: wrote C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\main.spec
3645510 INFO: UPX is not available.
3645513 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\yolov5\\Vision']
3645883 INFO: checking Analysis
3645886 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-07.toc is non existent
3645888 INFO: Reusing cached module dependency graph...
3645930 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
3646407 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-07.toc
3646410 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
3646475 INFO: Analyzing C:\yolov5\Vision\main.py
3650810 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
3650814 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
3654183 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook setuptools.extern.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
3657038 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook PyQt5.uic.port_v2 from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-PyQt5.uic.port_v2.py'.
3658566 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
3659745 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-six.moves.py'.
3717974 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pytorch'
3717979 ERROR: Hidden import 'pytorch' not found
3717982 INFO: Processing module hooks...
3717988 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-apscheduler.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718433 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-backports.zoneinfo.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718470 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718478 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-cv2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718492 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-eel.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718634 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-h5py.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718639 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3718644 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tensorflow.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3736361 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torch.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3736631 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-torchvision.ops.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3736635 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-tzdata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
3737595 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3737610 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3737615 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3737632 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3737701 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3738265 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
3738270 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
3738275 INFO: Packages required by gevent:
['setuptools', 'greenlet', 'cffi']
3739312 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3739330 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-importlib_metadata.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3739336 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3739382 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3740053 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo
3740378 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3740702 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Agg": ignored
    backend Gtk4Agg requires cairo
3741026 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK4Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3741351 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
3741679 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named 'IPython'
3742239 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtAgg": added
3742562 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "QtCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3743112 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
3743440 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3744411 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
3745373 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3745949 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
3746873 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
3747195 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
3747520 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
3747986 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
3748312 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffi is installed
3749354 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
3750369 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
3750924 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
3751401 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
3752333 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
3755084 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755422 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755439 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755582 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-packaging.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755589 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.io.formats.style.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755605 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.plotting.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3755868 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pandas.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756388 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756407 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756697 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756715 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756770 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3756789 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3757139 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
3757535 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
3757555 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3757618 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3757719 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758001 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtNetwork.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758344 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758660 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PyQt5.uic.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758671 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758808 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtCore.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3758912 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtGui.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3759292 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtNetwork.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3759734 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PySide2.QtWidgets.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760060 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pytz.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760237 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.io.matlab.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760244 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.linalg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760253 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760266 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760277 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.spatial.transform.rotation.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760341 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ellip_harm_2.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760349 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760358 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-scipy.stats._stats.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760368 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3760982 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761060 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761069 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761224 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761232 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761241 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761250 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761272 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761388 INFO: checking Tree
3761397 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-21.toc is non existent
3761405 INFO: Building Tree Tree-21.toc
3761475 INFO: checking Tree
3761484 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-22.toc is non existent
3761492 INFO: Building Tree Tree-22.toc
3761565 INFO: checking Tree
3761576 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-23.toc is non existent
3761584 INFO: Building Tree Tree-23.toc
3761598 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
3761982 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
3762184 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
3762226 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_subprocess.py'
3762237 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgutil.py'
3762249 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
3762259 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
3762273 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
3762286 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
3762296 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyside2.py'
3762308 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
3762320 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
3762418 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
3764103 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
3764968 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
3764981 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
3765185 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_tf_session.pyd
3765226 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_debug_events_writer.pyd
3765258 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_device_lib.pyd
3765288 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_events_writer.pyd
3765342 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_op_def_registry.pyd
3765375 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_record_io.pyd
3765405 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\_pywrap_file_io.pyd
3765440 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_traceme.pyd
3765470 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\internal\_pywrap_profiler.pyd
3765523 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_py_func.pyd
3765542 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\core\_pywrap_bfloat16.pyd
3765597 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\experimental\service\_pywrap_server_lib.pyd
3765630 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_checkpoint_reader.pyd
3765663 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\pywrap_saved_model.pyd
3765847 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\_pywrap_stacktrace_handler.pyd
3765876 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_test_metrics_util.pyd
3765992 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tfprof.pyd
3766015 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_tensor_float_32_execution.pyd
3766036 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_determinism.pyd
3766073 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_api_dispatcher.pyd
3766097 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_nest.pyd
3766120 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\_pywrap_utils.pyd
3766203 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_cluster.pyd
3766235 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\grappler\_pywrap_tf_optimizer.pyd
3766268 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_proto_comparators.pyd
3766296 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_dtypes.pyd
3766324 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\_pywrap_python_op_gen.pyd
3766399 WARNING: lib not found: inference_engine.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openvino\inference_engine\ie_api.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
3767760 INFO: Looking for eggs
3767772 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll
3767784 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
3767841 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\warn-main.txt
3768798 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\xref-main.html
3769191 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
3769211 INFO: checking PYZ
3769222 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-07.toc is non existent
3769234 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\PYZ-07.pyz
3778078 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\PYZ-07.pyz completed successfully.
3778250 INFO: checking PKG
3778261 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-07.toc is non existent
3778273 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg
3778340 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) main.pkg completed successfully.
3778353 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
3778365 INFO: checking EXE
3778378 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-07.toc is non existent
3778390 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-07.toc
3778402 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\main.exe.notanexecutable
3778419 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
3778432 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\video\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
3778447 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
3778461 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
3778474 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
3778488 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
3778500 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
3778514 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
3778526 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
3778540 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
3778555 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
3778568 INFO: Emedding manifest in EXE
3778581 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzqqe649s\build\main\main.exe.notanexecutable
3778596 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
3778611 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
3786949 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-07.toc completed successfully.
3786974 INFO: checking COLLECT
3786988 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-07.toc is non existent
3787000 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-07.toc
3809812 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-07.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\yolov5\VisionExe
Complete.
```

any help in solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you attempted to include pytorch as a hidden import, which is good.

```py
3717974 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'pytorch'
3717979 ERROR: Hidden import 'pytorch' not found
```

However, it seems the actual module name is just `torch` and not `pytorch`, what you had. You can also include specific portions, such as

```py
--hidden-import 'torch.jit'
```

I also noticed some warnings related to torch and tensorflow.

```py
3764103 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
3764968 WARNING: lib not found: c10.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
3764981 WARNING: lib not found: torch_cpu.dll dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd
3765185 WARNING: lib not found: _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd dependency of C:\Users\video\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\_pywrap_tf_session.pyd
```

I have not created an executable with these libraries before, but to play it on the safe side, I always include every library I touch (that is, I imported something in the code) in the hidden imports section. You might try modifying the .spec file that was generated in your project directory ([reference](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)) instead of typing each one out on the command line.

Finally, if the above fixes still produce the error, [try debugging the imports PyInstaller thinks it needs.](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports)

Edit: To fix the issue related to "lib not found", please add the following flags to the PyInstaller command (or include in spec file). There may be more or different ones for your specific case.

```
--add-data="c:\users\yourusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow;."
--add-data="c:\users\yourusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp37-win_amd64.pyd;."
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249132/pyinstaller-multiple-lib-not-found-warnings-when-compiling-py-file)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. indeed importing torch instead of pytorch removed that error. Unfortunately the exe still behaves the same. I have  a few questions tough: how can i find out that it is torch and not pytorch? the other warnings you listed search for a .lib. how can i include that, or where can i get that lib since i only installed with pip? (sorry noob here and first time trying this..)

Comment: A quick search turned up the following flags for your pyinstaller command (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249132/pyinstaller-multiple-lib-not-found-warnings-when-compiling-py-file)):
`--add-data="c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow;."` and
`--add-data="c:\users\chinu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd;."`

Comment: thanks, i found that link too yesterday, and tried it but did not solve. I dont understand those dll warnings, as in the compiled folder the dls are present.. so they are somehow found and copied over..

Comment: I gave you the +100 as they are soon going to expire and you were the only one trying to help me... the problem still persists tough.

Comment: Problem referring to the torch.jit overload function... does the code execute normally when run as a Python file and not a binary? At least in that case it can be definitively narrowed down to the Pyinstaller spec. Did you try the `--hidden-import 'torch.jit'` command?

Comment: @zodiac508 i have this autoPytoExe error :  VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
    Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

  while run_next_command(read_fh, write_fh):
41968 WARNING: lib not found: torch_python.dll dependency of C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\_C.cp38-win_amd64.pyd *what should i do?*